# Passing variables to constructor that may be defined

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

Having the below CDK construct:

```
export class MyConstruct extends kms.Key {

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, keyProps?: kms.KeyProps, topicProps: sns.TopicProps = {}) {
    super(scope, id, {...keyProps});

    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'Topic', {
      displayName: topicProps.displayName != undefined ? topicProps.displayName : "My Topic"
    });

  }

}
```

This creates a KMS key and a SNS Topic. My goal is to set certain values not defined for the `topicProps` variable. I've done this by looking if it was defined and otherwise create my own default.

My question now is, how would I pass in the other values in the `topicProps` attribute tot the `sns.Topic` constructor? Using `...topicProps` as input for `sns.Topic` would contain two values for `displayName`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you'd like to provide defaults for `topicProps`, if so... would something like this resolve your main ask?

```
export class MyConstruct extends kms.Key {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, keyProps?: kms.KeyProps, topicProps: sns.TopicProps = {}) {
    super(scope, id, {...keyProps});

    props: sns.TopicProps = {
     topicName: "defaultTopicName",
     displayName: "defaultDisplayName",
     ...topicProps
    };        

    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'Topic', props);
  }
}
```